# Chained Fetch getting first results immediately

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I am sending chained `Fetch` requests. First, I retrieve data from database and request pictures related to every title I got.

The `HTML` code won't be loaded to results `div` before image `requests` are sent. So it takes long time to see articles. How can I make the text to load before image `requests` starting to be sent?

```
async function getArticles(params) {
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/api/?'
    url2 = 'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=XXX&content_filter=high&orientation=landscape&per_page=1&query='

    const article = await fetch(url + params).then(response => response.json());

    const cards = await Promise.all(article.results.map(async result => {
        try {
            let image = await fetch(url2 + result.title).then(response => response.json())

            let card = // Creating HTML code by using database info and Splash images
            return card

        } catch {
            let card = // Creating HTML code by using info and fallback images from database
            return card
        }
    }))
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = cards.join("")

};
```

I have tried using them separately but I was getting Promise Object.

Comment: Don't use `Promise.all()`, that waits for all of them to resolve. Use a `for` loop that does `await fetch` and adds that response to the DOM sequentially.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, could you please add code? I didn’t get where to use that loop and how. Because I’m already mapping results from first fetch

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to wait for all the fetches, use an ordinary `for` loop and await each one sequentially.

```js
async function getArticles(params) {
  url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/api/?'
  url2 = 'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=XXX&content_filter=high&orientation=landscape&per_page=1&query='

  const article = await fetch(url + params).then(response => response.json());

  for (let i = 0; i < article.results.length; i++) {
    let result = article.results[i];
    let card;
    try {
      let image = await fetch(url2 + result.title).then(response => response.json())
      card = // Creating HTML code by using database info and Splash images
    } catch {
      card = // Creating HTML code by using info and fallback images from database
    }
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += card;
  }
}
```

However, this will be slower because it won't start each fetch until the previous one completes.

It's hard to run all the fetches concurrently but display the results in the order that they were sent, rather than the order that the responses were received. You could do it by creating a container DIV for each response before sending, then filling in the appropriate DIV when its response is received.